# How to force a City entity to have its name available in all locales (languages)?

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I would like to design a database where the city name **MUST** exist in all the available locales (languages). I currently serve these locales:

**en**, **fr**, **it** and **es**.

My initial thought is to save the name inside the `cities` table but instead of having ***one*** `name` field, I'd have `name-en`, `name-fr`, `name-es` and `name-it`.

Thus, the city of London would be saved like this inside the `cities` table:

[image]

My second thought is that it'd be more *production-appropriate* to have a table of all served `locales` so that once we add a new locale it'd appear on the website automatically as an extra option. Thus, I made this ERD:

[image: ER diagram]

Which means that the many-to-many between `City` and `Locale` would generate the following table:

[image]

So far so good, but I'm not sure how to **FORCE** that once a new city is added it **MUST** has it's name available in all locales. Or is that only possible using backend code?

Note:
This is a hiring assignment, so I don't have specific business rules just to think of a smart and **scalable** solution.

Thanks.

Comment: A (scalable) workaround/solution might be using a "staging table" where you store the many-to-many where you insert/update and have the triggers on... And let the triggers copy the data from the "staging" to the "live" table when translations for a city are added/updated for all locales and delete the copied data from the "staging"..  What way the "live" table does not have the trigger "overhead" plus you have enforced the business rules, assuming you also revoke insert/update rights for all users on the "live"

Answer (score 1):

In your first solution, you can use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint check_all_names
    check (name_en is not null and name_fr is not null and name_es is not null and name_it is not null);
```

The second is basically not possible with a well-designed data model in SQL.  Why?

- To insert into `city_locales` you need a valid `city_id`.
- By definition, you cannot have a valid `city_id` until you have all locales.

Further, constraints generally need to be true as rows are inserted.  You cannot insert one row into `city_locales` and have the constraint be true (assuming you have more than one `locale`).

One way around this would be to have a flag on the `cities` table that specifies if all locales are created.  You can update the number of locales using a trigger.  Or, you can use a view and calculate the flag on the fly.